# Joining database values and add to an array using Java

Tags: java, arrays, database, resultset

This is part of my **web service** **java** project in netbeans. 
I do not know how i can **retrieve** the **two** value from my database(the **description** + the **culture** - these are the **columns**), **add** them both to an **array**, and then **retrieve** them **both** later.
I know how to do this when retrieving just **one** value.

```
   public String countries(@WebParam(name = "name") String name) {
            //TODO write your implementation code here
            try {
                String url = "jdbc:odbc:" + "worldcup"; 
                Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");

                Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"","");

                // Gets a statement
                Statement state1 = con.createStatement();
                //Statement state2 = con.createStatement();

                String query1 = "SELECT description,culture FROM Countries WHERE name = '" + name + "'";
                // selects the description for the selected group ( group will be referenced to the chosen group)
                ResultSet results = state1.executeQuery(query1);
                int i = 0;

                Arrays.fill(names, "");
                while (results.next()) {
                    String nam = results.getString("description"); // <---- this is the part i need help from
                    names[i++] = nam;
                }   

                return Arrays.toString(names);

            } catch (SQLException e){

                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

            }
            return null;
```

Comment: String nam = results.getString("description") + " "+results,getString("culture ");

Comment: Thanks!! That makes sense, i didn't know how to combine them.

Comment: I would create object of class Country. for every row in ResultSet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the value either through column name or column index.

Access by Column Name.

```
names[i++] = results.getString("description");

names[i++] = results.getString("culture");
```

Access by column index.

```
names[i++] = results.getString(1);

names[i++] = results.getString(2);
```